# Cloud Firestore crashes everything

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a Flutter app using Firebase. However, I encountered some issues when using the Firestore feature. When I add cloud_firestore and try to run the app, everything crashes and my computer uses 100% of the CPU until it ends. Then VSCode launches a very long error that starts with:

```
Move<true>(absl: :make_index_sequence<sizeof... (Ts)>0,
In file included from /Users/fscozano/Desktop/cicciofn/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/channel/promise_based_filter.cc:17:
In file included from /Users/fscozano/Desktop/cicciofn/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/channel/promise_based_filter.h:37:
In file included from /Users/fscozano/Desktop/cicciofn/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/channel/call_finalization.h:24:
In file included from /Users/fscozano/Desktop/cicciofn/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.h: 72:
In file included from /Users/fscozano/Desktop/cicciofn/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/transport/transport.h: 60:
/Users/fscozano/Desktop/cicciofn/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/transport/metadata_batch.h: 1250:10: note: in instantiation of member function 'grpc_core:: Table<grpc_core::metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core: :HttpPathMetadata>, grpc_core: :metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core: :HttpAut horityMetadata», grpc_core::metadata_detail: Value<grpc_core: HttpMethodMetadata>, grpc_core: :metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core: :HttpStatusMetadata>, grpc_core: :metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core: :HttpSchemeMetadata>, grpc_core: metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core: :Content TypeMetadata> grpc_core: :metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core::TeMetadata>, grpc_core::metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core::GrpcEncodingMetadata>, grpc_core: :metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core::GrpcInternalEncodingRequest>, grpc_core: metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core: :GrpcAcceptEncodingMetadata>, grpc_c ore: :metadata detail::Value<grpc_core::GrpcStatusMetadata>, grpc_core: :metadata detail?: Value<grpc_core::GrpcTimeoutMetadata>, grpc_core::metadata detail::Value<grpc_core::GrpcPreviousRpcAttemptsMetadata>, grpc_core: :metadata detail::Value<grpc_core:: GrpcRetryPushbackMsMetadata>, grpc_ core: :metadata_detail: :Value<grpc_core::UserAgentMetadata>, grpc_core: :metadata detail:: Value<grpc_core::GrpcMessageMetadata>, grpc_core: :metadata_detai1:: Value<grpc_core: :HostMetadata>, grpc_core: :metadata _detail:: Value<grpc_core: :EndpointLoadMetricsBinMetadata>, grpc_core:: metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core: :GrpcServerStatsBinMetadata>, grpc_core: metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core::GrpcTraceBinMetadata>, grpc_core::metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core: :GrpcTagsBinMetadata>, grpc_core: :metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core::GrpcLbClientStatsMetadatas, grpc_cor
e: metadata_detail: :Value<grpc_core::LbCostBinMetadata>, grpc_core: :metadata detail::Value<grpc_core::LbTokenMetadata>, grpc_core::metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core: :GrpcStreamNetworkState>, grpc_core: :metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core: :PeerString>, grpc_core: :metadata _detail:: Value «grpc_core: :GrpcStatusContext>, grpc_core: :metadata_detail:: Value<grpc_core: WaitForReady>>:: operator=' requested here
table_ = std: :move(other. table_);
```

I couldn't find anyone that had the same issue. The problem isn't related with the app because I tried using the default flutter app (the one with a button and the counter) and had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from the cocoapods. Try to clear all pod caches then reinstall it.

Firstly, stop your running app, then in the terminal:

```
cd ios
pod cache clean --all
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods                                                        
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate 
pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: It didn't work. If you have other ideas let me know please. Thanks for your help